# iPhone app crashes after resigning active state (after core data wipe)

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, crash

My app uses core data for data storage, and I added code that handles cases where the database/model is not compatible/corrupt/etc. In this case, I will present an error message, prompting the user to wipe all of the data, and restart the app, so the user can start again from scratch.

The problem is, that the app will crash after the storage was deleted and the user pressed the homebutton. My wipe code looks like this:

```
// destroy context

if ([__managedObjectContext hasChanges])
   [__managedObjectContext rollback];

[__managedObjectContext release];
__managedObjectContext = nil;

// remove store

if (__persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.count)
   [__persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:[__persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:localURL] error:nil];

NSLog(@"retain count: %p %d", __persistentStoreCoordinator, __persistentStoreCoordinator.retainCount);

[__persistentStoreCoordinator release];
__persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;
```

Interestingly the retain count of the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is 1, therefore the release above will dealloc the object.

When the user now presses the homebutton, I will get this in the console:

```
*** -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8345530
```

The printed address `0x8345530` in this example is equal to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` object released in the above code. The backtrace looks like  this:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0178be1e in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x0178bce2 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#2  0x0122c75e in -[_NSSQLCoreConnectionObsever _purgeCaches:] ()
#3  0x00345a39 in __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 ()
#4  0x017f0885 in ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 ()
#5  0x017f07a8 in _CFXNotificationPost ()
#6  0x0028a1aa in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#7  0x005e6169 in -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] ()
#8  0x005ee8bd in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
#9  0x005ef1f8 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#10 0x005e2aa9 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#11 0x01e45fa9 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#12 0x017f91c5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#13 0x0175e022 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#14 0x0175c90a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#15 0x0175bdb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#16 0x0175bccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#17 0x01e44879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#18 0x01e4493e in GSEventRun ()
#19 0x005e0a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#20 0x000046fd in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff63c) at main.m:24
```

After a complete restart the app will of course work just fine again, with a plain new and empty storage file.

The above code is from my app delegate subclass, and the properties are declared like this:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;


@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

What I just dont understand is, how can any object still use the OLD store coordinator instance when the retaincount obviously reached zero? I don't ever use/access this object outside of the app delegate class.

[edit] Just ran instruments (Zombie-mode), which yields similar results:

http://i41.tinypic.com/317ci91.jpg

As can be seen from the backtrace already, some purge-caches method is causing the crash. What is it, and how can I make it use the NEW store coordinator instance, and not the zombie one?

Comment: retainCount is useless.   Don't call it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `[self saveContext];` and place it in `applicationWillTerminate:` before the app has terminated. And you shouldn't use `retainCount` to see if an object is overreleased or overretain. You should user instrument instead

Comment: Thanks for the hint, ill try instruments. What is [self saveContext]? Also, the problem occurs without the app beeing terminated (just backgrounded), e.g. applicationWillTerminate is not fired. As you can see above, i'm querying the managedobjectcontext for pending changes, and roll them back before destroying the objects.

Comment: Added picture from instruments above.

Comment: I think what you want is create a new persistentStoreCoordinator? did you use `[self persistentStoreCoordinator];` ?

Comment: No, I do not want to create a new coordinator. The problem is, the app crashes while accessing the OLD, dealloc'ed coordinator, and I don't know why/where.

Comment: because you have dealloc it and never init? how do you try access the persistentStoreCoordinator, how about changing the `_persistentStoreCoordinator` to `[self persistentStoreCoordinator]`

Comment: I don't access the old object. It is accessed by the coredata lib (-[_NSSQLCoreConnectionObsever _purgeCaches:]) but I don't know why.